# automate page scroll using vbscript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation, browser-automation

I need to take complete snapshot of a page using vbscript, and to do this I need to scroll a bit down. Actually I am able to take half of the page in snapshot but I need to take the remaining part also in the next snapshot.

I tried using following once the page is loaded

```
ie.document.body.doScroll("pageDown")
```

But it is not scrolling the page down, is there any better way to do this, Actually I don't want to have a page down scroll but just 100 pixels down, Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [scrollBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) over parentWindow.

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 100
'as relative new.x = current.x + (0), new.y = current.y + (100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this: **Window.Scroll x, y**

```
Window.Scroll 0, 0
```