# Scraping IE with VBA, how to scroll to bottom of page?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am pretty new to VBA. I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of a web page. Below is contents of web page.

```
<DIV id="Table">

<div style="width: 18px; overflow: auto; height: 912px;" onscroll="Grids[0].Scrolled();" onmousemove="Grids[0].ARow=null;Grids[0].ASec=-1;"><div style="width: 1px; overflow: hidden; height: 1954px;">&nbsp;</div></div>'
```

This is VBA Code I have so far.

```
Dim selector As String
selector = "#Table div[style*='onmousemove']"

Dim rightWindowDiv As HTMLDivElement
Set rightWindowDiv = htmldoc.querySelector(selector)
rightWindowDiv.ScrollTop = rightWindowDiv.ScrollHeight
```

Somehow it does not work. Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you want to scroll? does the site updates some data only when you scroll down to it? Edit: Different question but the answer applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790471/automate-page-scroll-using-vbscript In short: `htmldoc.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 100`

Comment: Yes, the site only update part of data. The data could be as much as few thousand line depend on your search. I tried parentWindow but it doesn't scroll page at all. The page is setup to have the search result displayed on lower right of the web page and has its own scroll bar.

Comment: It seems that it may be broken down in iframes, meaning that the lower right may be a different page. You may want to see in the code or properties. If it is a different page under an iframe, your vba code should open that iframe.

Comment: Can you share the webpage url?

Comment: To Ricardo, thanks for the reply. I will take a look at coding to see if iframe is the issue. But I have question since I was able to get partial data, is this really the iframe issue?

Comment: To QHarr, unfortunately, this is a private website, I cannot share the site. Appreciate for your help anyway.

Comment: Does the scrolling generate any web traffic you can examine in dev tools or fiddler?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, yes I think so, when I scroll, I can see the loading icon and data won't immediate display but it did show how many lines the search found. For example, it might found 100 rows of data but only display 30 rows at a time. The number of lines display at a time depend on browser zoom level.

Comment: One thing I have question is onscroll="Grids[0].Scrolled()"? That doesn't look like normal scroll seem in the webpage instead as function call upon. I did notice that source code did mention it is part of js script. I did not know vba well enough in this case do you have to do something different?

Comment: Anyone has anymore ideas to try it? Any help is appreciated.